# Jquery - tag attribute with escaped html gets unescaped automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

I have this div with a data attribute that may contain escaped html value

```
<div id="test" data-title="&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;Hello&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;"></div>
```

Now, when I read the value of data attribute, It's automatically being unescaped.
For example, following code will cause the alert to show up.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").append($("#test").data("title"));
  });
```

See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FJTW8/3/

Why is it getting unescaped, and what's the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //alert($("#test").data("title"));                
    $("#test").append(escape($("#test").data("title") ) );
  });
```

Comment: It got unescaped because you appended it to the html element without escaping it again, updated the fiddle too, http://jsfiddle.net/FJTW8/4/

Answer (score 0):

This code will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#test").text($("#test").data("title"));
});
```

Because .append() is the same as .html();

Answer (score 0):

the answer is not quite right
you should do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){              
    $("#test").append(htmlEntities($("#test").data("title") ) );
  });
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FJTW8/16/